# Assign a remote for Git Push

Tags: git

I've been developing in a local repository for a while and just set up a git server.

In the past, when the remote repo already exists, I can do a `git clone`, and then future `git push` just works -- it seems to be associated with the remote that `git clone` retrieved.

Since I want to push all my existing work to this fresh remote, I did a `git remote add foo`.  But `git push` still doesn't work, I have to do a `git push foo master`.

How can I make `foo master` be the default so that `git push` works on it's own?  And secondly, did I approach this in the right way?  How would you populate a new remote repo with an existing local repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `git push` to push to a remote without any additional parameters, rename that remote from `foo` to `origin`.

Comment: If you really want it to be called `foo` then you could make an alias for pushing to foo. Look for `alias.*` on http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html

Answer (score 1):

By default `git push` will try to push to a remote called `origin`, which is automatically created by `git clone` to point to the repository you cloned from. There's probably a `git` command to set a branch's remote, but I don't know it; you can edit `.git/config` manually though. Find the section for the branch you're pushing from (e.g. `[branch "master"]` if it's the master branch), and change `remote = origin` to `remote = foo`

Comment: You can use
    'git remote rename <old_name> <new_name>'
To erase the old origin and make foo the new one
    'git remote rm origin'
    'git remote rename foo origin'

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the remote origin url:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
git config --edit
```